# Name mismatch in UK BRP and passport

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

My name is wrongly mentioned in my UK biometric residence permit (BRP). Say the actual name printed on the passport be "John Richard Doe", with "John  Richard" as the first name and "Doe" as the surname. However, in the BRP, the name is printed as "John" as the first name and "Richard Doe" as the surname.

I am travelling outside the UK next week and feel there will be issues during the UK exit/entry. I didn't notice this error when the BRP was issued, and don't think there is enough time to correct the BRP.

Does this situation require immediate correction on the BRP before travel? If so, is there a way to speed up the BRP correction process?

Answer (score 1):

The names on any identification document are taken as a whole. It would only be a problem if there were a real discrepancy in total, such as John Richard Doe on one ID but Richard John Doe or John Henry Doe on the other. The first and other names plus surname = your registered i.e. official full name. There is therefore no "mistake" in theory.